# How to insert array's key and values in php codigniter

Tags: php, mysqli

**I have a array in this format**

```
Array
(
    [1] => india
    [2] => False
    [4] => B
    [5] => C
)
```

**Each array values are be placed in multiple row....How to do this like that can you please anyone explain this?**

i nee to like this table below

```
id   answer
1     india
2     false
4     B
5     C
```

Comment: please first post you effort!

Comment: sir actually i am fresher... Ill know insert the single variable values in sql table..but i dont know idea to how the arrays key and value insert in multiple records...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new array from getting a key-value array. Here I have used the model name `Answer_model`, you can load your model name and load it.

```
$testArr=Array( 1 => 'india',2 => 'False',4 => 'B',5 => 'C'); // Here gettting array pass to `$testArr`


$arr=[];
foreach ($testArr as $key => $value) {
   $arr[]=array('id'=>$key,'answer'=>$value);
}

$this->load->model('Answer_model'); //Load model
$ans= $this->Answer_model->insertBatch('answer',$arr);// Here answer is table name where we have to insert record
```

In Answer_model model

```
public function insertBatch($table, $data)
{

    $result = $this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```